# Abelian Subgroup of Normal Subgroup of Solvable Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

This is Exercise #11 from Section 3.4 of Dummit and Foote (and is a common question in various texts), but I have not found a satisfactory answer on this site (and in some cases people misstate the definition of a solvable group given in D&F).  My hope is that I will not only understand a solution to this problem but in doing so also see how to combine various big ideas, such as products of groups, the isomorphism theorems, and normal subgroups.

The problem as set forth in D&F is "Prove that if $H$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of the solvable group $G$ then there is a nontrivial subgroup $A$ of $H$ with $A \underline{\triangleleft} G$ and $A$ abelian."

The D&F definition is "A group $G$ is $solvable$ if there is a chain of subgroups

$1 \, = G_0 \, \underline{\triangleleft} \, G_1 \, \underline{\triangleleft} \, G_2 \, \underline{\triangleleft} \ldots \underline{\triangleleft} \, G_s \, = \, G$

such that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian for $i = 0, \, 1,\ldots, \,s-1$."

My approach has been to attempt to find something isomorphic to $G_{i+1}/G_i$ because then I would have an isomorphism to an abelian.  Based on ideas from other postings, I considered letting $G_i$ be the largest index such that $G_i \cap H = {1}$ and then we would have $G_{i+1} \cap H \neq {1}$.  Perhaps letting $A = G_{i+1} \cap H$ might lead me somewhere.

This is the place where I am trying to combine the second (i.e., triangle) isomorphism with normal subgroups and am getting stuck.  Mightily stuck, I might add.

It seems to me that $H \underline{\triangleleft} \, G_{i+1}$ and by definition $G_i \underline{\triangleleft} \, G_{i+1}$ so that $G_{i+1}H/H \cong G_{i+1}/(G_{i+1} \cap H)$.  That did not seem to work, but it got me to consider another product.

I decided to try $G_i (G_{i+1} \cap H)$ and put that at the top of the diamond (for the second isomorphism theorem).  Then $G_i$ is on the left and $(G_{i+1} \cap H)$ is on the right with $G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H)$ at the bottom.

Now my isomorphism is $G_i (G_{i+1} \cap H)/G_i \cong (G_{i+1} \cap H)/ (G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H))$.

Here I observed that $G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H) = (G_i \cap H) = {1}$.  Recall that I am using $A = (G_{i+1} \cap H)$.  That means my isomorphism is actually

$G_i A/G_i \cong A/{1}$.

This seems ever so close.  If I knew that $G_i A/G_i$ is abelian then I would be there.

Am I on the right track?  Am I completely in the wrong direction?  Is there a gap (simple or not) that I am missing?  Lastly, please excuse the length of this posting, but I wanted to be thorough with the statement of the problem, the related definitions, and my thinking.

Comment: Even if you proved that $A$ was abelian you would not be finished, because you do not know that $G_{i+1}$ is normal in $G$, and so you would not know that $A$ is normal in $G$. There is of course an equivalent definition of a solvable group in which the $G_i$ are all required to be normal in $G$. I would be inclined to start by proving that D&F's definition implies this equivalent property.

Comment: You are of course correct regarding the requirement of showing $A \underline{\triangleleft} G$.  An earlier exercise in D&F (#8 in section 3.4) pertained to finite solvable groups, but #11 has no such restriction.  I know that being "normal" is not transitive (i.e., $G_1 \underline{\triangleleft} G_2 \underline{\triangleleft} G_3$ does not imply that $G_1 \underline{\triangleleft} G_3$), and I am struggling to figure out how to show that $A$ is normal in $G$. Does it have something to do with the fact that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian?  Can you give me a slight nudge in the right direction?

Comment: With your current formulation I don't believe that it is possible to prove that $A$ is normal in $G$, and it might not be true in general. I am suggesting that you start with a series $G_i$ (such as the derived series of $G$) in which all $G_i$ are normal in $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Hmmm.  Can I reformulate $H$ and thereby make the task of showing $A \underline{\triangleleft} \, G$ a bit easier?

Comment: @DerekHolt Does my amended answer go in the direction you were suggesting?

Comment: You need the derived series. Without it, you will never be able to solve this problem.

Comment: @David Thank you for your reply and effort.  I had seen that posting before doing my own post and found it a bit confusing (especially with the continued return to the derived series in various places), but I suppose the final amendment to the answer in that other posting might work.  My urge now is to carry on and hope that things clear up a bit when I finally reach the derived series in D&F.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. You're almost there. $G_iA/G_i$ is abelian, because its a subgroup of the abelian group $G_{i+1}/G_i$.

Answer (score 0):

@DerekHolt wrote "With your current formulation I don't believe that it is possible to prove that A is normal in G, and it might not be true in general."  That prompted me to look at my $A$ to see what I could do, especially in view of the commutators.

We are given that $H \underline{\triangleleft} G$, which means that $ghg^{-1} \in H \; \forall \; g \in G, h \in H$.  From that we have $ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \in H$, so $[g,h] \in H$.

Now I decided to reformulate my $A$ by using the commutators of $G$ and let the group $C = \langle [x,y] \rangle = \{ xyx^{-1}y^{-1} | x,y \in G \}$ be the commutator group of elements in $G$. Lastly, I set $A = C \cap H$.

We know that $C \underline{\triangleleft} G$ and are given that $H$ is normal in $G$ so their intersection is normal too, which means $A \underline{\triangleleft} G$.  Because $A$ contains commutators of $G$, $A$ is abelian too.

Comment: The derived subgroup of a group is not abelian in general. So $C$ is non-abelian in general, and so $C\cap H$ need not be abelian. You cannot prove this result using anything like this. You need the derived series I think. Derek Holt is right, you cannot use an arbitrary abelian series for $G$.

Comment: @David Well, then, I am stumped.  D&F does not introduce the derived series until page 196, and the problem that is the subject of my original question is on page 108.  Surely there must be some way to solve the problem using the tools in D&F.  Can no one tell me how?